# HAproxy domain name to backend mapping for path(url) based routing

Tags: haproxy

Does HAProxy support domain name to backend mapping for path based routing.

Currently it does support maps for vhost:

```
frontend xyz
   <other_lines>
   use_backend backend1 if { hdr(Host) -i myapp.domain1.com }
   use_backend backend2 if { hdr(Host) -i myapp.domain2.com }
```

Can be rewritten using maps as:

```
frontend xyz
   <other_lines>
   use_backend %[req.hdr(host),lower,map_dom(/path/to/map,default)]
```

With the contents of map file as:

```
#domainname  backendname
myapp.domain1.com backend1
myapp.domain2.com backend2
```

But if the routing  is based on paths as shown in the example below:

```
frontend xyz
   acl host_server_myapp hdr(host) -i myapp.domain.com
   acl path_path1 path_beg /path1
   acl path_path2 path_beg /path2
   use_backend backend1 if host_server_myapp path_path1
   use_backend backend2 if host_server_myapp path_path2
```

Is it possible to have mapping for this usecase?  Using `base` instead of hdr(host) might give the entire path but it will not have the flexibility of domains since `base` is string comparison. Is there an other way to convert this to haproxy maps.

Comment: In case anyone encounters this question: here's a "duplicate" which has a good answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37858336/haproxy-domain-name-to-backend-mapping-for-pathurl-based-routing